# how to create video from animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create video from animation, or export animation to video. I know we can create video from UIImage array, but how to create video from animation of UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this manually. 
Basically you have to use the AVAssetWriter to generate a movie, for which you need to provide each and every frame. 
So instead of using the CAAnimation, you have to determine the state of your UIImageView for each of the frames, and write that to the AVAsset.
I hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This means I need design each frame by myself instead of using the animation and transition directly.